# SQL: Problems with IN clause, how to return for ALL values, even duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I want:

```
SELECT someID FROM table1 WHERE someID IN (1,1,2,2,3)
```

to return

```
someID
1
1
2
2
3
```

while it now return only distinct values from the IN clause, like this:

```
someID
1
2
3
```

I use Microsoft SQL Server and my table contains a unique someID and PLSRec.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table1](
    [someID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PLSRec] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_table1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
```

How about something like?:

```
DECLARE @table2 table(someID int)

INSERT INTO @table2(someID) VALUES (184),(132);

SELECT * FROM @table2 LEFT JOIN table1 ON @table2.someID=table1.someID
```

(except the INSERT INTO-sentence returns "Incorrect syntax near ',')

Comment: Which database? It returns multiple rows for me. See my response below

Comment: Also, what's the sample data? Please post as SQL (`CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements) to make it a [useful sample](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I think I might have a solution, but don't know how to work it out:

If I create a table2 using a WITH clause, that contains a column with rows:
1
1
2
2
3

then I can use SELECT * FROM table2 LEFT JOIN table1 ON table2.someID = table1.someID

How do I write the WITH-clause to create table2?

(Sorry for not knowing how to write this in other ways than in plain text)

Comment: Again, please update the question mentioning the database you use and the `create table` and `insert` statements. As @Outis said.

Answer (score 3):

This can only be accomplish by a [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product), a.k.a. `JOIN`. In this case, `INNER JOIN`. You need to make a rowset containing all those values, like this:

```
SELECT 1 as someID
UNION ALL SELECT 1 as someID
UNION ALL SELECT 2 as someID
[...]
```

Then, using it in a `JOIN` clause (with CTEs if you're using MS SQL)

```
SELECT table1.someID FROM table1
JOIN (SELECT 1 as someID
UNION ALL SELECT 1 as someID
UNION ALL SELECT 2 as someID
[...]
) as table2 on table1.someID=table2.someID
```

Of course, this IS an extremely ugly solution.

Comment: I don't know if it's less ugly, but you can do without the product, just concatenate: SELECT someID FROM table1 WHERE someID = 1 UNION ALL SELECT someID FROM table1 WHERE someID = 1 UNION ALL SELECT someID FROM table1 WHERE someID = 2

Comment: In SQL Server `SELECT FROM derived_table` can be used which can make the above code significantly prettier :-) See [Table Value Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx) for details, which creates a valid `derived_table`. Sample: `SELECT a, b FROM (VALUES (1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 10) ) AS MyTable(a, b);`

Comment: @Thilo, I use rarely `Union all`, that's why I don't remember when `ALL` is to be missed.
@pst, thank you for this, I didn't know :)

Answer (score 2):

It will only check the row's someID against the values of the IN().

It doesn't matter how your IN() looks like, it will not return more results than there are rows that matches that value.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have misunderstood something. Your code is mere syntactic sugar for

```
SELECT someID 
  FROM table1 
WHERE (
       someID = 1 
       OR someID = 1 
       OR someID = 2 
       OR someID = 2 
       OR someID = 3
      );
```

Your "IN clause" is not a set: if you want it to be then use a table e.g. CTE, inline derived table, static VIEW, table variable, etc. But note that a set does not have duplicate rows!

Answer (score -2):

I haven't tried it but

```
SELECT someID, count(someID) FROM table1 WHERE someID IN (1,2,3) group by someID
```

may serve your purpose.

Or

```
SELECT someID id1, someID id2 FROM table1 WHERE id1 IN (1,2,3)
```

might work

EDIT: Which database? I am using Sybase SQLAnywhere and it does return multiple rows.

Comment: I think because it doesn't answer the question :( Poster wants the records with id's 1 and 2 to be returned *twice* because 1 and 2 appeared *twice* in the `IN`.

Comment: The OP didn't mention which RDBMS. As I wrote in some it already returns the multiple rows. Otherwise, since it is only selecting one field, the *only* use they can be is to know how many times they are repeated and my first query can be used for that. Oh well.

Comment: No. He doesn't want "multiple rows". He wants *one row per item in the `IN` clause* (even if said item is a duplicate), as per the examples. The code above results in the case which he *does not* want. It's a silly question, yes, but this doesn't answer it.

Comment: Oh. Wow. You are right, yes. I guess I misread because I would have never thought anyone to want to do this. Thanks for explaining.